# Google Maps MarkerClusterer ignores several styling properties

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm using the Google Maps MarkerClusterer to cluster Map Markers ( Who would have thought! ). The problem I'm having is, that certain styling properties don't affect the marker.

Here's a list of all properteis that can be used http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html

The properties `height` , `textSize`, `textColor` , `url`, and `width` work without any problems. But when trying to change the `fontWeight` nothing happens. I've tried it out with these propteries.

```
var styles = [[{
    url: imagePath,
    width: x,
    height: y,
    anchor: [0, 0],
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    textSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 100 // as well as `fontWeight: 'normal'`

}]];
```

But still there are no changes. Are there other people with the same issues?

Comment: no issues for me, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Sure. http://jsfiddle.net/j4vft/1/

I just pasted the "interesting" stuff in there. Hope it's enough.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/issues/detail?id=324

Answer (score 0):

In documentation it says fontWeight value must be a string, but you're sending a number. Can you try `fontWeight: '100'`?

Comment: Tried it as well as `fontWeight: 'normal'` but didn't work either.